# Qt Creator split editor for source and header

Tags: c++, qt, ide, qt-creator, header-files

Qt Creator 4.2.1
The editor in this IDE can be split. It would be nice if header and source files will be load into those two after (for example) double clicking on project tree. Do you know any way, maybe a plugin for this? Now I am using F4 for switching between source and header.

It also would be nice to see only one item in project tree for header-source pair - it would take less place.

Comment: Sounds like a feature request for Qt Creator. That's probably best directed towards the [Qt Company](https://www.qt.io/) (or whatever they are called this week).

Comment: You may consider using the `Class View` to avoid two lines for each class.

Comment: @m7913d unfortunately, this view doesn't show directories and I have too many classes for flat view.

Comment: Are you using a `.pro` file? My version of Qt Creator (4.1.0) groups all the source and header files in a separate (virtual) `Headers` and `Sources` folder.

Comment: @m7913d in this particular project I am not. I am using `PROJECT_NAME.creator` with additional files `.config`, `.files` & `.includes`. Header files are not always in the same dir as source. But F4 figures it out.