# How to stop Qt Creator from switching to .cpp file when adding definition to it with opened splits?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have two splits that are opened side by side - file.cpp and file.h.

Now, if I right-click a method/function in file.h, go to *Refactor* and click *Add definition in file.cpp*, Qt Creator will add definition and automatically open file.cpp in current active split, despite the fact that file.cpp is already opened in another split. So, now I have two splits with file.cpp and I need to manually set one split back to file.h. This is so annoying because I want to have both .cpp and .h opened at the same time, all the time.

Is there a way to stop Qt Creator from opening file in an active split when adding definitions if there is already that file opened in another split?

Comment: Possible duplicate with my old question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44384708/qt-creator-split-editor-for-source-and-header

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. There doesn't exist an option for that, at least I couldn't find it. One could find relevant parts in source code and add one if-statement that would solve that, but I am to lazy to go through that effort. Maybe to submit a request at Qt's bug tracker of Qt's forum, or something.